# Confused with DataStream keyBy method in case of parallelism

Tags: apache-flink

I have following simple flink code. The NumberSource is extending SourceFunction, so that its parallelism is 1.

```
  test("keyBy + parallelism") {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(new Configuration())
    env.setParallelism(3)
    val ds = env.addSource(new NumberSource()).keyBy(_ % 3).process(new KeyedProcessFunction[Int, Int, String] {
      override def processElement(value: Int, ctx: KeyedProcessFunction[Int, Int, String]#Context, out: Collector[String]): Unit = {
        val key = ctx.getCurrentKey
        out.collect(s"$key-$value-${System.identityHashCode(this)}")
      }
    }).setParallelism(3)
    ds.print().setParallelism(2)
    env.execute()
  }
```

In the KeyedProcessFunction, I returns the function object's address using `System.identityHashCode(this)`. Since it's parallelism is 3 by calling `setParallelism(3)`, I think 3 different object address should be printed out.

But, when I run the application,only one address is printed out, that means, all the records are processed by only one process function.

Shouldn't `keyBy` method route the record to the correct partition in the downstream operator?

I wonder whether I have understood something wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment of a key to a sub-task isn't straightforward. Flink will use a Murmur3 hash on the key, then assign it to a "key group", and that finally gets assigned to a sub-task. So there's not a direct mapping from key value 1 to sub-task 1, for example.

It is possible, via some fragile code, to calculate a key that will get assigned to a specific sub-task.